# function template instantiation in unevaluated context

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the following program well formed?

```
template<typename T>
void f() { T{}.m; }

using u = decltype(f<int>);
```

Here's the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/yybxFN) to experiment with.

Instantiating `f<int>` would be wrong, but `f<int>` is not used in an evaluated context here, so I think it should be ok. clang agrees, however gcc complains with:

```
In instantiation of 'void f() [with T = int]':
error: request for member 'm' in '0', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

I don't understand why gcc is instantiating anything here.

So is this code ill formed, or is it a gcc bug?

Comment: This works fine on msvc too. Strangely, if you remove the definition, it works, but if you add the definition after the typedef, it stops working again: https://godbolt.org/z/cQp_37

Comment: @Artyer That makes sense, since the declaration of `f` should be all that's needed. If the definition is provided, then gcc seems to want to instantiate it. Looking for the definition after the `using` is allowed, so that part is ok (I think).

Comment: A piece of wording: [the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#4). Might look vague to me.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I thought `decltype` doesn't require the definition to exist. In fact, if there is no definition, gcc is fine with the program. The cwg issue seems interesting, I'll have to read that in detail, thanks.

Comment: @cigien I also thing `decltype` doesn't require. I think the issue not really relevant here, because the function is not even called under `decltype`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, I don't think the issue is relevant here. Well, the examples are only using class templates, and not function templates, so I'm not sure. And as you say, the function is not even called.

Comment: I, too, am of the opinion that this code should work and GCC is wrong to instantiate the body of the function.

Comment: It works starting from GCC 11: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cvdvq4Mhs

Comment: @Fedor Ah, thanks. Yeah, that certainly makes it almost guaranteed that it was a GCC bug.