# Why doesn't decltype instantiate this recursive function prototype?

Tags: c++, templates, decltype, template-instantiation

I created the following code to create a sequence of numbers from 0 to N inclusive. I'm aware there are better methods with O(log N) instantiation depth like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence), but that isn't the focus.

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t... Ns> struct hasNums;

template<bool> struct hasBool;

template<std::size_t... Ns> 
hasNums<Ns...>* makeNums(hasBool<false>*);

template<std::size_t First, std::size_t... Ns> 
constexpr
decltype(makeNums<(First - 1),First,Ns...>(
static_cast<hasBool<static_cast<bool>(First - 1)>*>(0)
) ) makeNums(hasBool<true>*);

template<std::size_t... Ns>
void method(hasNums<Ns...>*){

}

int main()
{
    method(static_cast<decltype(makeNums<20>(static_cast<hasBool<true>*>(0)))>(0)) ;
  
}
```

[Link to the code in cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGNzdGRkZWY+Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTxzdGQ6OnNpemVfdC4uLiBOcz4gc3RydWN0IGhhc051bXM7Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTxib29sPiBzdHJ1Y3QgaGFzQm9vbDsKCnRlbXBsYXRlPHN0ZDo6c2l6ZV90Li4uIE5zPiAKaGFzTnVtczxOcy4uLj4qIG1ha2VOdW1zKGhhc0Jvb2w8ZmFsc2U+Kik7Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTxzdGQ6OnNpemVfdCBGaXJzdCwgc3RkOjpzaXplX3QuLi4gTnM+IApjb25zdGV4cHIKZGVjbHR5cGUobWFrZU51bXM8KEZpcnN0IC0gMSksRmlyc3QsTnMuLi4+KApzdGF0aWNfY2FzdDxoYXNCb29sPHN0YXRpY19jYXN0PGJvb2w+KEZpcnN0IC0gMSk+Kj4oMCkKKSApIG1ha2VOdW1zKGhhc0Jvb2w8dHJ1ZT4qKTsKCnRlbXBsYXRlPHN0ZDo6c2l6ZV90Li4uIE5zPgp2b2lkIG1ldGhvZChoYXNOdW1zPE5zLi4uPiopewoKfQoKaW50IG1haW4oKQp7CiAgICBtZXRob2Qoc3RhdGljX2Nhc3Q8ZGVjbHR5cGUobWFrZU51bXM8MjA+KHN0YXRpY19jYXN0PGhhc0Jvb2w8dHJ1ZT4qPigwKSkpPigwKSkgOwogIAp9&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0)

Running the code on cppinsights reveals that only `method` is instantiated, and this is only so I can see that the numbers 0 to N are indeed being produced. I was surprised because I thought I'd see instantiations of `makeNums` too. How can the compiler create this index sequence without other instantiations?

Comment: Related to [function-template-instantiation-in-unevaluated-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840943/function-template-instantiation-in-unevaluated-context)

Comment: What did you expect to see instantiated? There isn't even a body of `makeNums` available. Anyway `decltype` is an unevaluated context. The body isn't needed.

Comment: @rustyx Something like `template<> constexpr decltype(makeNums<19,20>(static_cast<hasBool<true>*>(0)) makeNums<20>(hasBool<true>*)`, the steps it took to make the sequence [N - 1, N], then [N - 2,N], etc.

Comment: Well I guess cppinsights shows only instantiated bodies... it looks like some kind of clang AST hack anyway...